# Database content loading optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I am making a simple blog on react (nextjs) + redux. The main page contains a list of all articles. The problem is that each query to the database with loading even a small number of articles takes time. How can this be optimized? There is an idea to put these articles in redux on initial load. Is this a good idea? Or are there any better ways?

Comment: Where exactly is the query to the database being made from? Are you using SSG or SSR? Can you share some of the code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I will suggest is to have lazy loading. In this case, the app won't load every blog, and also you can just show the blog name and image and load the blog once someone wants to read it/ click it.